# My UTC Timezone function not displayed on HTML using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

When using `innerhtml` so you can see the time zone, it doesn't display in the result.

Javascript code:

```
function roughdraft() {
  var d = new Date();
  var z = document.getElementById("result");
  var utcsinceepoch = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds());
  var y1 = d.getTime()
  z.innerHTML=(d.getTime() - utcsinceepoch)/3600000;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="picture"></div>
    <form>
      <input id="UTCoffset" type="text" placeholder="UTC Time Zone">
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if I'm doing the wrong innerhtml syntax.

Comment: why this code should display time zone? are there any errors in console (browser's development tools)?

Comment: Would missing a `;` after `var y1 = d.getDate()` have anything to do with it?

Comment: This is my own function.  I'm using javascript's built in functions `Date.UTC()` returns the number of milliseconds from 1/1/1970, at the 0 UTC time zone.
`.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds from 1/1/1970, in the client's time zone.

Comment: I added the semicolon, but the code still didn't edit the `p`

Comment: try adding ; before z.innerHTML as @MikeDtrick pointed out. That's a parse error. Also, at what point are you calling the roughdraft function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function roughdraft() {
 var d = new Date();
 var resultParagraph = document.getElementById("result");
 var utcsinceepoch = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds());
 var y1 = d.getTime();
 resultParagraph.innerHTML=(d.getTime() - utcsinceepoch)/3600000;
}

roughdraft();
```

Comment: I just forgot to call the function.

Comment: @user252297 :) you're welcome. It happens to every body... and when you are in a rush this kind of "bug" can become a nightmare (I've been there).

Comment: I might sound obnoxious but a good method would be to add comments and "reminders" that you need to call some functions. ;)

Comment: That helps with debugging.